# Invoice created via REST API causes error in PayPal backend

Tags: c#, rest, api, paypal, invoice

Last year I created a sample appliation that could create, send and check PayPal Invoices using the REST API. Everything worked like a charm, the invoices showed up in my sandbox seller backend and it just worked.

Today I use the exact same unmodified application to create an invoice draft. The response is OK, I can even "send" the invoice (apart from the fact that nobody's getting any emails...), I can get its status (which is DRAFT or SENT for example) - everything seems to be fine.

Only that in the new-style backend for the seller's sandbox account instead of a list of drafts I get an error message saying that an error occurred and I should reload the page (which of course doesn't help at all). When I delete the above created draft, everything is back to normal again and I can see my old drafts from last year. I create a new draft, I get the error again, and so forth.

The same thing happens on the live page as well, so it doesn't seem to be a sandbox issue.

I use the NuGet packages for the PayPal REST API and the classes therein. I now found that I can view the JSON that's being sent to PayPal. The request looks like this (anonymized the buyer and seller emails - all other fields are unchanged and worked with the same values last year):

```
{
    "number": "RE2017072701",
    "merchant_info": {
        "email": "seller@xxxxx.de",
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "User",
        "address": {
            "phone": {
                "country_code": "49",
                "national_number": "1234595959"
            },
            "line1": "Teststraße 15",
            "line2": "Gewerbegebiet",
            "city": "Testingen",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "postal_code": "12345"
        },
        "business_name": "Testfirma GmbH",
        "website": "http://xxxxxcompany.de",
        "additional_info": "Hier steht noch weiterer Text!"
    },
    "billing_info": [{
        "email": "buyer@xxxxx.de",
        "first_name": "Kundenvorname",
        "last_name": "Kundennachname",
        "address": {
            "line1": "Kundenstr. 1",
            "city": "Kunden",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "postal_code": "99999"
        }
    }],
    "items": [{
        "name": "ITM0001",
        "description": "Ein Artikel für 199,99€",
        "quantity": 1.0,
        "unit_price": {
            "currency": "EUR",
            "value": "199.99"
        },
        "tax": {
            "name": "MwSt.",
            "percent": 19.0
        },
        "date": "0001-01-01 UTC"
    }],
    "invoice_date": "0001-01-01 UTC",
    "payment_term": {
        "term_type": "DUE_ON_RECEIPT",
        "due_date": "0001-01-01 UTC"
    },
    "tax_calculated_after_discount": false,
    "tax_inclusive": true
}
```

The following is the JSON response (again, I anonymized the email addresses):

```
{
    "id": "INV2-LTSS-QW3C-DQS5-G8RF",
    "number": "RE2017072701",
    "template_id": "TEMP-7H507227XX2795902",
    "status": "DRAFT",
    "merchant_info": {
        "email": "seller@xxxxx.de",
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "User",
        "business_name": "Testfirma GmbH",
        "website": "http://xxxxxcompany.de",
        "address": {
            "line1": "Teststraße 15",
            "line2": "Gewerbegebiet",
            "city": "Testingen",
            "postal_code": "12345",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "phone": {
                "country_code": "49",
                "national_number": "1234595959"
            }
        },
        "additional_info": "Hier steht noch weiterer Text!"
    },
    "billing_info": [{
        "email": "buyer@xxxxx.de",
        "first_name": "Kundenvorname",
        "last_name": "Kundennachname",
        "address": {
            "line1": "Kundenstr. 1",
            "city": "Kunden",
            "postal_code": "99999",
            "country_code": "DE"
        }
    }],
    "items": [{
        "name": "ITM0001",
        "description": "Ein Artikel für 199,99€",
        "quantity": 1.0,
        "unit_price": {
            "currency": "EUR",
            "value": "199.99"
        },
        "tax": {
            "name": "MwSt.",
            "percent": 19.0,
            "amount": {
                "currency": "EUR",
                "value": "31.93"
            }
        },
        "date": "0001-12-31 PST"
    }],
    "invoice_date": "0001-12-31 PST",
    "payment_term": {
        "term_type": "DUE_ON_RECEIPT",
        "due_date": "0001-12-31 PST"
    },
    "tax_calculated_after_discount": false,
    "tax_inclusive": true,
    "total_amount": {
        "currency": "EUR",
        "value": "199.99"
    },
    "metadata": {
        "created_date": "2017-07-27 03:11:19 PDT"
    },
    "allow_tip": false,
    "links": [{
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices/INV2-LTSS-QW3C-DQS5-G8RF",
        "method": "GET"
    },
    {
        "rel": "send",
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices/INV2-LTSS-QW3C-DQS5-G8RF/send",
        "method": "POST"
    },
    {
        "rel": "update",
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices/INV2-LTSS-QW3C-DQS5-G8RF/update",
        "method": "PUT"
    },
    {
        "rel": "delete",
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices/INV2-LTSS-QW3C-DQS5-G8RF",
        "method": "DELETE"
    }]
}
```

What is wrong here?

PS: Oh, and should I mention that of course I can manually create invoices on the web page successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, by going back to a minimal invoice, which then worked, I was able to single out the date values as the source of the problem. Obviously it is OK to pass `DateTime.MinValue`, but then the PayPal WebSite doesn't handle it properly.

Passing `null` instead of `DateTime.MinValue` for unused dates fixes the issue. It should be noted that passing `DateTime.MinValue` used to work.

Case closed.